# Can I exempt a single file in iCloud directory from deleting locally?

Tags: icloud, storage

I use the "storage optimisation" feature on my Mac. Part of this feature is that it deletes local files to save on local storage, and files can then be downloaded when needed.

I like this feature. However, I want to be able to prevent certain files that I use frequently from deleting locally.

When I am working offline, it is very frustrating to go to open a file only to find that it has been deleted locally and I cannot open it without finding an internet connection.

To be clear, I do not want to prevent syncing. I just want to keep the file permanently on my local hard drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is currently no file or folder level controls for storage optimization. It's an all or nothing feature, which is really too bad.

Here are your options as I see them:

#### Option 1: Turn off Storage Management

*System Prefs -> Apple ID -> (uncheck) Optimize Mac Storage*

By default this keeps everything. You can *Right click -> Remove Download* for any files in an iCloud drive you don't want to keep locally. But you'll have to manage them by hand.

#### Option 2: Move the file out of an iCloud folder

Storage Management will stop deleting the file, but it also stops syncing.

#### Option 3: Use another service

You could keep Storage Management on for most files but move the things you need more control over into another cloud service (ie dropbox) that does what you want.

#### Option 4: Open the file frequently

In theory Storage Management will keep files you "open frequently". You could probably even do so automatically if you're comfortable with a command line:

For Example:

```
export VISUAL=nano
crontab -e
```

`0 12 * * * touch -a /Users/yourname/path/to/file`

Should make the OS think you've used the file every day at noon. Make sure to pick a time when your computer is on.